# change color of bookmark bar in Firefox 91

Tags: firefox, css

I have changed the color of the top "tool bar" in userChrome.css:

```
#nav-bar {
    background-color: #1f3f7c !important;
    color: white !important;
} 

/* Bookmark bar color */
#main-window #PersonalToolbar {
    background-color: #1f3f7c !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

but this does not change the bookmark bar.
How can I change the color of the bookmark bar as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the bookmark bar's colour the ID in the current version of Firefox is personal-bookmarks

So the userChrome.css you need would be

```
#nav-bar {
    background-color: #1f3f7c !important;
    color: white !important;
}

/* Bookmark bar color */
#personal-bookmarks {
    background-color: #1f3f7c !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

[image: bookmarks toolbar with custom colours]

You can find this kind of information by looking through [browser.css](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.css) and looking for likely candidates.